# php calling html

Tags: php

can you please let me know what I am missing:

```
<html>
<head><title>page</title></head>
<body>
<h2><center>Welcome to the mainpage</center></h2><br />
<a href="sample4.php?currpage=2">Home page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

php code is :

```
<?PHP

$currpage=$_GET['currpage'];


echo "Hello world $currpage"; 
?>
```

when I click the homepage I want the sample4.php script to be executed and that output which is a html page to be displayed.
But when I click the homage page : I get a file window download.

I have the php script in the same location I have the html?

Comment: What web server are you running (Apache, IIS, nginx, etc)? Looks like a content type misconfiguration

Comment: do you have PHP interpreter installed and configured?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but you're not closing the `<a>` element properly, it should be `<a href=sample3.php?currpage=2>Home page</a>`

Comment: fixing the </a> is also not working

Comment: Ia m running XAMPP-Apache in widows

Comment: I am able to run php programs. only issue is with html calling phph

Comment: @Kishore well at least that part is fixed...

Comment: no I already have </a>. when I copy pasted that part is messed up

Comment: There is no "call" from anything to anything here. When you click a link on a webpage, any webpage, a brand new HTTP request is made from the browser to the server. Aside from a referrer header, there is no difference between clicking a link and typing a URL in the address bar yourself. So your problem is unrelated to this HTML and is only a question of server configuration.

Comment: @Kishore Thota use quotes around the href (and close it properly) `<a href="sample3.php?currpage=2">Home page</a>`

Comment: i agree but why is my script not running...all I want is in the php program to print helloworld followed by that value I am semding

Comment: @Kishore if you did, and still doesn't work, didn't it strike that the problem might not reisde HERE but in your php? show that code (and the part where you get the url parameter

Comment: htmlcode: <html><head><title>page</title></head><body><h2><center> 
    
Welcome to the mainpage</center><h2><br />

<a href="sample4.php?currpage=2">Home page</a></body></ht

Comment: php code: <?PHP

$currpage=$_GET['currpage'];


echo "Hello world $currpage"; 
?>

Comment: @Kishore Edit your question instead of adding more comments, especially for code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="sample3.php?currpage=2">Home page</a><p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do what you want? Otherwise, you'll need to show us the PHP code, in case it's making it a download from within the PHP.

For a hello world program, try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php 
    $currpage = isset($_REQUEST['currpage']) && is_int($_REQUEST['currpage'])?(int)$_REQUEST['currpage']:1;
    echo "<p>Current page is $currpage</p>\n";
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

You may also need to make sure that PHP is installed and running on your machine/server...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php 
    phpinfo();
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Suggested edit: USE QUOTES around the href. `<a href="sample3.php?currpage=2">Home page</a>` otherwise the two `=` might cause problems in rendering the correct adress.

Comment: its like a helloworld program. I get that value and print that in a html page

Comment: I am trying to get the following working: php: <?PHP

$currpage=$_GET['currpage'];


echo "Hello world $currpage"; 
?>
 =======================html <html><head><title>page</title></head><body><h2><center> 
    
Welcome to the mainpage</center><h2><br />

<a href="sample4.php?currpage=2">Home page</a></body></html>